# WPF .Net Core 3.0 mapping language primitive types in Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core

One of the issues I'm facing while converting WPF application from NET Framework 4.7 to .Net Core 3.0 is a problem with mapping primitive types like Double in XAML. In NET Framework this XAML has worked perfectly:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    >

   <sys:Double x:Key="BaseSize">10</sys:Double>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

However mscorlib does not exist in .Net Core. How can I map primitive types in XAML in .Net Core 3?

Had tried this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/built-in-types-for-common-xaml-language-primitives

But for WPF this does not work as it is stated here:

"*In WPF, you can use XAML 2009 features but only for XAML that is not markup-compiled. Markup-compiled XAML for WPF and the BAML form of XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 keywords and features.*"

Comment: I had exactly the same error, sending me off on a wild goose chase. In my case it was an unrelated missing resource the error given was misleading, fixed the resource and primitive type error went away

Answer (score 11):

You can use the exact same markup when targeting .NET Core 3.0, i.e. `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` does actually work. Any reference to `mscorlib` is type forwarded to `System.Runtime` automatically.

Try to build the solution or take a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/708) if you don't believe me.

**Edit:** Starting with .NET Core 3.1, you should replace `assembly=mscorlib` with `assembly=System.Runtime`.

Comment: In .NET Core 3.1 you need to specify `assembly=System.Runtime` instead of `assembly=mscorlib`.